# Replacing Shutoff Valves on PEX Tubing

Tags: plumbing

I have a bunch of these shutoff valves in my condo:
[image]
[image]

Almost all of them have developed a leak and I'd like to replace them with something better. I did a little research and it seems like the valves are attached to PEX tubing using PROPex fittings. I found a couple sources explaining how to remove them using heat and a utility knife and I was thinking of using push fittings (the specific brand being SharkBite Push-To-Connect).

My main question is: After I remove the old valve (assuming I actually can) do I need to cut the PEX before putting a new valve in?

The other question I have is: Am I missing any steps?

1. Turn off main water source
2. Bleed the pressure from the lines
3. Remove the existing shutoff valve
4. Trim the PEX (or don't depending on the answer to my first question)
5. Put the new valve in
6. Turn on the water

P.S. Please excuse my dirty floor :(

Comment: Push fittings want very square ends of the right size.  They will leak if the ends not perfect.  Imagine the fitting you have now if removed will not leave PEX end as new.

Comment: Looks like Uponor PEX connections. Google that and see if you can get info on easiest removal. Never seen valves like that: plastic PVC? Where is it leaking from? It is possible to take the valve apart and lube with silicone? Redo a connection? What country is this?

Comment: OK, I see you are in Calgary. Looks like boomtown construction. If you would heat this to remove it, you might then need to cut it 2 inches from the section heated! Seems like it would be better to just make a square cut without heating. There is a lot that has been learned about remediating PEX connections. Don't plunge into this without studying the matter. E.g.,  https://youtu.be/tJI-E6y2DuU

Comment: Thanks for the info @JimStewart, I think you're right that I would be better cutting the old connection out. I'll definitely do some more research before I jump in but at least I know how to go about it now. Definitely boomtown construction, everything looks nice but under the covers it's pretty questionable