# Leaking toilet supply shutdown valve

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, toilet, valve

How do I fix/service this leaking toilet shutoff valve connection?

I do not have the name for this type of connection, and I am unable to find replacement parts and instructions on how to repair it/them. This is the shutoff valve that controls/supplies water to the toilet's tank. To the right of the white combination valve is the flex/braided toilet connector/supply line.

[image]

Comment: That looks like this:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/246572/replacing-shutoff-valves-on-pex-tubing

Comment: @SteveWellens Go ahead and make an answer including that linked question. The comments there suggest how to fix it and the pictures there clearly show the through-wall connection. Good find!

Answer (score 4):

Don't fix it.   Replace it with a new better one.  Buy what's available, you don't have to hunt around for parts for an obscure valve that is crap to begin with.

There are [countless](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=replace%20plastic%20toilet%20shut%20off%20valve) youtube videos showing prideful plumbers replacing sh*tty plastic valves with better new ones.  Watch some of those.  Turn off the main supply, remove this valve attempting minimal destruction to the supply pipe, and put in a better one.

Most of the youtube demos will use press fittings.  For a beginner DIY project like this I recommend a Sharkbite quarter-turn valve.  I think they sell one in a kit for a toilet with an included supply hose.  IDK what country you're in ... if not, get advice from the store.

It's a great beginner project, except that if you screw up your whole house will be without water until you sort it out.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a shutoff valve, as you stated in the question. Some variant on an "angle stop valve" evidently.

The particular one seems a bit odd (to me), but either it is common local to you and your hardware/plumbing supply will have a matching replacement, or it's also uncommon and you'll replace it with a more normal valve or possibly an elbow and a more normal valve.

You may need to shut the water off further upstream for the duration of the trip to the hardware/plumbing supply store with the problem valve. Or you may be able to take these pictures; or new pictures with a ruler included for scale, to your hardware/plumbing supply store.

Comment: Any idea on how to proceed with taking this apart? It is not clear to me what components are designed to be loosened or removed in order to service this connection. Am I supposed to make a hole in the wall, cut the pipe at the round plate that sits flush with the wall, buy a new pipe, and use a component to join the existing wall plumbing to whatever I purchase from the hardware store?

Comment: @PorLosTacos The braided toilet supply hose end can be unscrewed first. Use an open end wrench or an adjustable wrench on the metal hex end. Then, work your way back along the plastic, again using a wrench on the hex flats. The bigger parts may unscrew by hand or a strap wrench.

Comment: @Armand, yes, the metal hex end is easy enough to remove. Also, it appears that the fitting/adapter that mates the braided toilet to the plastic angle stop valve appears to have something to grab onto for loosening purposes (red box). I am stumped, back to my question posed to 'Ecnerwal', is how do I physically disconnect/remove the parts that I am going to replace (yellow box)?

The red and yellow boxes are displayed in the image (that I just replaced) from the original post.

Comment: You'll need to experiment. It's not obvious from here if the angled body unscrews or pulls out of from the fitting at the wall, or if it is glued in place, and won't be obvious there until the toilet hose is disconnected. At most, you cut off where there's normal pipe and connect to the normal pipe, with or without a coupling and more pipe as needed.

Comment: @PorLosTacos I see plastic hex sides before your red box. The red box looks like slip joint pliers or a strap wrench would undo it. The part between red and yellow boxes should unscrew with hand or strap wrench or slip joint pliers. The elbow looks like it should unscrew or just pull out from the cup coming out of the wall. You'll have to look behind the escutcheon (or remove/cut it off) to see what's going in to the wall.